# Retrieve wordpress custom field (group) data inside jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

Inside my themes’ included main.js I have to retrieve some data entered via wordpress into a range of custom fields (within field groups). How can I pass the php values into the jQuery code?
To be more specific I am creating multiple google map markers within my initializeMap() function as follows:

```
var markers = [
                ['First Center','First Address',50,50],
                ['Second Center','Second Address', -25.363882,131.044922],
                ['Third Center','Third Address', 10.363882,95],
                ['Fourth Center','Fourth Address', -50,-90],
                ['Fifth Center','Fifth Address', 30,5],
            ];

            for( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);                  
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: markers[i][0],
                    icon: image
                });
            }
```

With the help of the ACF wordpress plugIn it was easy to create the custom fields to edit from inside my wordpress. Each custom field group named "Center 1", "Center 2"… contains the 4 fields for "Center name", "Center address", "Latitude" and "Longitude". But now the task is to transfer this data into my markers field. Anyone with an idea? I know this is not easy. Thanks a lot, guys!

**EDIT:**

The guys from ACF plugin helped me out so far. Generally the code that I needed was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {

window.map_data = [];

window.map_data.push( ['<?php the_field('center_name'); ?>', '<?php the_field('center_address'); ?>', <?php the_field('latitude'); ?>, <?php the_field('longitude'); ?>]);

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

that I put at the very end inside my “az_google_maps.php” template given by my Wordpress theme. Then I managed to retrieve that “map_data” array inside my js file. The rest will be (as suggested by HdK) doing a loop and somehow tell the code how many fields are actually defined by the user inside the Wordpress editor. I am working on that. Have patience with my little js/php knowledge. Would be awesome not getting down voted a thousand times. But guess that’s part of the game here. So, ok ;-)

Comment: Have you tried anything? You're going to need to loop through your fields and `echo` them into your JS variable.

Comment: That’s what I hoped someone would explain to me. How is this to be done and where? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your required javascript inside your theme template instead of your main.js and than do something like:

```
<script>
var markers = [
    [<?php echo get_field('center-name'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('center-address'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('lat'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('lng'); ?>]
</script>
```

Also take a look at this example page: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

Comment: Sounds interesting. Maybe I could store the variable from there globally? Because I will not be able to program everything new. :-( But can you give me a hint which .php doc the "template" is, when inside wordpress on my specific site it shows up with "default template"? I cannot find anything named "default template" round here…:-(

Comment: But even given that I found the right place to put this code (I will try with index.php at the end after the last ?> I wonder how I can specify first the field group the fields belong because they are all the with the same name. Oh, see, this will be too much for my little knowledge…

Comment: If it isn't a custom template, you could copy the default template and make a custom template of it. Add `/* Template Name: GoogleMaps */` at the beginning of the file and you should be able to select it on the required page.

As for the fields, you should loop over them so you can reuse the names, but with different values.

Answer (score 1):

You could list all your data on a `<input type="hidden">` via `WP_Query`. Let me show you an example:

Create the query and pass all information to the `<input type="hidden">`

html:

```
<?php 
    $args = array('post_type' =>array('YOUR_CUSTOM_POST'), 'exclude' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC');
    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $q->have_posts() ): while( $q->have_posts() ): $q->the_post();

    $address = get_field('address');
?>

<!-- I created some data attributes to store all content -->
<input type="hidden" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-address="<?php echo $local['address']; ?>" data-lat="<?php echo $local['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $local['lng']; ?>">

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In jQuery inside your map's functions right after you create the map object, you can use `.each()` to loop through all `<input type="hidden">` like this:
function createMarker(){

```
...
..
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
        // vars to store all contents
        title   = $(this).data('title');
        address     = $(this).data('address');
        lat     = $(this).data('lat');
        lng     = $(this).data('lng');

        //var to the box that will wrap the marker's content
        content = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+title+'</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p>Endereço: ' + address + '</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        // create a infowindow to display the content
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
        });

        //create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map:map,
            title: title
        });

        // listener to open infowindow on click
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    });
}           
createMarker();
```

Hope that'll help

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and providing me your code. Appreciate that, Ramon! For the solution I guess I will use see my edit above! Thanks again!